# Linear Independence

Tags: linear-algebra

I've come across a question in Linear Algebra that I can't quite figure out. I've tried a multitude of things that either don't work or aren't sufficient enough to convince me I understand linear independence well enough.

I know a set of vectors, S, in vector space V are linearly independent if their linear combination, that is,

$\lambda_1 \mathbf{v}_1 + ... + \lambda_n \mathbf{v}_n = \mathbf{0}$

means all scalars are equal to each other and 0,

$\lambda_1 = ... = \lambda_n = 0.$

I can also show a set of vectors S is linearly independent if I'm given a set of vectors with numerical values - by creating a matrix and reducing it to row echelon form. However, my understanding isn't great enough that I can expand on this and answer questions such as the following:

Assume the vectors **u, v** and **w** are linearly independent elements of a vector space V. 
For each of the following sets decide whether it is linearly independent.

A. {**u** + **v** + **w**,  **v** - 2**w**,  2**u** + 3**w**}

B. {**u** + 2**w**, **v** + 2**w**, 2**w**}

C. {**x, y, z**}

where,

**x** = **u** + 2**v** - **w**,

**y** = 2**x** + **u** + 2**v** - **w**,

**z** = 3**x** - 2**y**.

If anyone can explain to me the connection between this type of question and the definition of linear independence by answering A or providing a guideline of how to answer A then hopefully I can tackle B and C and any related questions. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You basically need to write the definition of linear independence. Suppose that 
$$
\alpha(u+v+w)+\beta(v-2w)+\gamma(2u+3w)=0. 
$$
We can rewrite this as 
$$
(\alpha+2\gamma)\,u+(\alpha+\beta)\,v+(\alpha-2\beta+3\gamma)\,w=0.
$$
Since $u,v,w$ are linearly independent, we get the equalities 
$$
\alpha+2\gamma=0,\ \ \alpha+\beta=0,\ \ \alpha-2\beta+3\gamma=0. 
$$
Now you can analyze this system. If the only solution is $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$, you'll know that the three vectors in A are linearly independent. If you produce a nonzero solution, you'll know that they are linearly dependent.

Comment: Thank you. So can I put these equations into a matrix and row reduce? And if it reduces to the identity matrix does that mean it is linearly independent as the solution is trivial?

Comment: Exactly. $ \ \ $

Comment: Brilliant thanks very much

Answer (score 4):

*Hint:* In both cases, write the coordinates of the vectors in the set with respect to the original set as rows in a matrix. Row reduce this matrix.

Comment: While this is clever, I doubt if OP would be able to see why this method works

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the definition. For the first case you can write:

$$\lambda_1(u+v+w)+\lambda_2(v-2w)+\lambda_3(2u+3w)=0$$

now rewrite like:

$$(\lambda_1+2\lambda_3)u+(\lambda_1+\lambda_2)v+(\lambda_1-2\lambda_2+3\lambda_3)w=0$$

Now use that $u,v,w$ are independent, solve the system and find $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\lambda_3$.

Can you finish?

Answer (score 1):

for A: we have
$$\alpha(u+v+w)+\beta(v-2w)+\gamma(2u+3w)=0$$
this is equivalant to
$$u(\alpha+2\gamma)+v(\alpha+\beta)+w(\alpha-2\beta+3\gamma)=0$$
can you finish?
for B: we get
$$u\alpha=0,v\beta=0,w(2\alpha+2\beta+2\gamma)=0$$